# android indexof an arraylist returned by getInstalledPackages

Tags: java, android

What is the object parameter in indexOf() when used with the List returned by getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)?   I have done a Collections.sort on the list with a comparator comparing packageName.    I want to get the indexOf based on a string that is a packageName but I cant figure out how that parameter will be formed.  I've tried

```
PackageInfo searchInfo = new PackageInfo();
        searchInfo.packageName = procName;
        int nameIndex = packs.indexOf(searchInfo);
```

and it returns -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at this code.Here you can compare with packageName.....

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
             get a list of installed apps.
            packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;



                      }
```

Comment: I am already using an iteration but it is taking a long time and I hoped that a sort and indexOf would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

check this line:  `int nameIndex = packs.indexOf(searchInfo);` and observe `searchInfo`

Comment: Sorry I dint put my question very clearly.   I need to know how the object parameter should be formed in order for it to work properly.